# Как смонтировать новое сетевое расположение electronjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, fs

Пытаюсь создать программу на подобии **https://www.rushfiles.com/** на electronjs, не получается реализовать часть с добавлением нового расположение подобно этому:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

принцип работы такой: когда запускаем программу, монтируется вот такое расположение, после, иттерируются имена файлов которые получили из базы,
пытался использовать этот либ **https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-network-drive**
но в место того чтобы создать новое соедянение, клонировался диск C со всеми файлами
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
, использовал код из этого примера **https://github.com/larrybahr/windows-network-drive/blob/master/example/write-a-file-to-a-network-drive/index.js**

Answer (score 0):

Протестировал в ноде, монтирует корректно:

```
let networkDrive = require("windows-network-drive");
networkDrive.mount("ТУТ СЕТЕВОЙ ПУТЬ", "R", undefined, undefined)
```

Comment: получил такую ошибку https://prnt.sc/1v43z3r

Comment: ```let networkDrive = require("windows-network-drive");
networkDrive.mount(NETWORK_DRIVE_PATH, 'R', undefined, undefined);```

Comment: как выглядит NETWORK_DRIVE_PATH ? Предположу, что он должен начинаться с ////

Comment: ```const os = window.require("os");

const username = os.userInfo().username;

const NETWORK_DRIVE_PATH = `//${username.split('-').join('')}`;```
ну и затем

```networkDrive.mount(NETWORK_DRIVE_PATH, 'R', undefined, undefined);```

Comment: `////${username.split('-').join('')}` попробуйте так

Comment: добавил, всё ровно та же ошибка что и на скрине

Comment: можете мне пример своего путя отправить, по которому у вас заработало?

Comment: Блин, моя ошибка, \\\\NT_PC,  Обратите внимание на  слеши \\\\

Comment: ну в данном случае поставим мы \\\\ или // будет одинаково, nodejs \\\\ преобразует в //